# Did Krishna play flute ever post Gokul days?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita, bhagavata-purana, kurukshetra

It is said that Lord Krishna did not play flute after he had left Gokul. But most of the pictures of Lord Krishna ( adult) is shown with the flute. Did he play flute in later period?

Comment: This is on a lighter note. Flute might have reminded Krishna of his carefree childhood days and love of his life, Radha. So growing up he might have decided not to play it and instead picked up the conch shell.

Comment: I scarcely remember from BRC MahAbharata episode for its conversation between Bhishma & Krishna, where Krishna had stopped playing flute. Neither that serial can be considered fullproof nor do I remember exactly.